# What is the correct way to cite a character in a novel?

Tags: bibtex

Suppose I have in my document a reference `Nov` to a novel and I want to draw out an idea formulated by a character.
If I quote the novel itself it might look like it's a position the author is advocating, so I'd like to have something like "(Character in the work of Author Date)" or something semantically close.

What would be the correct Bibtex syntax?

Comment: I think this is something you need to resolve 'manually' by structuring your sentence in a way to avoid confusion. If your readers are aware that Elk 1990 is a novel, it would probably be enough to say `As Edgar says: 'Blub' \cite[120]{elk}`. Of course you could also say `'Blub' \cite[Edgar in][120]{elk}` if your citation package supports prenotes. Just to be clear: I don't think there is a standard solution for this in the LaTeX world. You'll have to use what you think makes sense (which is not really a LaTeX question, but a writing/academic question) and try to make LaTeX produce that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let's say it would a LaTeX question if there was a standard package or method, but if there is none, indeed there is nothing more to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need an idea of what the output should look like in your example. This is less of a LaTeX question than a writing/academic question. I can imagine that the following would be acceptable

> Edgar describes knowledge as 'justified true believe' (Elk 1998, p. 120)

or

> 'And what is the use of a book without pictures or conversation?' (Alice in Carroll 1865, p. 5)

If you have already established that you are talking about novel and its characters, I can imagine that no additional hint is necessary to make your readers realise what is going on.

---

Once you know what the output should look like, you can try to make LaTeX produce that output for you.

The exact solution will depend on your bibliography and citation package, so it's hard to say something that is generally applicable. If you don't want to  mention the character in the citation itself and resolve the ambiguity in your text, you of course don't need additional markup. If you want to mention the character explicitly in the citation output, you can use the prenote argument that some citation packages (`natbib`, `biblatex`, but crucially not the standard kernel definition of `\cite`) support

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \enquote{ipsum} \autocite[Alice in][120]{sigfridsson}

Alice mentions \enquote{dolor} \autocite[121]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem ‘ipsum’ (Alice in Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 120)//Alice mentions ‘dolor’ (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, p. 121)]